# webpack MV3 webworker target usage

Tags: typescript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

I'm trying to convert an old Chrome MV2 project to MV3. The build system uses webpack. I understand from the documentation that I should set the target as "webworker" to build a service worker for MV3 to replace my MV2 background page.

I have the following code included in my webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'esbuild-loader',
        options: {
          loader: 'ts',
          target: 'webworker'
        }
      },
    ],
  },
```

When I use this configuration, changing only the previous "es2015" to "webworker", the build fails
with the following error:

```
  Error: Invalid target: "webworker" (valid: esN, chromeN, edgeN, firefoxN, iosN, nodeN, safariN)
```

The documentation hints that the WebpackOptionsApply plug-in may be involved, but I get a failure when I use that. I have tried setting up arguments to this plug-in, but I haven't found any that work.

```
  plugins: [
    new WebpackOptionsApply(),
```

There doesn't seem to be much documentation around using webpack for MV3 service workers that I can find and I'm no typescript or webpack expert. Moving from typescript or from webpack isn't a viable option for us. If I revert to using "es2015" as the target, I get "window" references being drawn-in from some (unidentified) included library that I will need to eliminate for MV3. I'm hoping to use "webworker" to identify and eliminate whichever library that is.

Comment: Here's a hack, assuming that `window` is only used to get the `global` reference: use wrapper-webpack-plugin and add `self.window = self;` header.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm this solved this issue. I also had to remove the "use strict" from the header in order to get things working.